# How do I hide the master part of a UISplitViewController programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my UISplitViewController, I want the "master" part of the view to hide itself and the "detail" part take over the full screen when the user clicks a button in landscape. Likewise, clicking the button again takes the user back the standard, split screen view. Is it possible to do this with the built-in class?

Comment: You mean like in the Facebook App? If not there's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700453/how-to-hide-master-view-in-uisplitviewcontroller-in-ipad

Comment: That other question is only when the app changes orientation though. In this case, I want pretty much that same behavior to activate when a button is pressed instead.

Answer (score -1):

There's a method you can implement from UISplitViewControllerDelegate in iOS5:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc 
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc 
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

[MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) has that functionality built in for pre-ios5 work.