# UISplitViewController - Hide master slide-in view

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a `UICollectionViewController` in its master view controller. When the device is on portrait orientation, the user can swipe the screen to reveal the master view.

When a collection cell is selected, the detail view is updated with new data. Now I'd like the master view to hide automatically at the same time. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide master view in UiSplitviewcontroller in ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700453/how-to-hide-master-view-in-uisplitviewcontroller-in-ipad)

Comment: Check the highest scoring (not the selected answer) in the duplicate I noted.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese I'm aware of that feature. That will control whether the master view should be hidden or not depending on the orientation. However, I want to control the master view that slides-in (that used to be the pop over), and not the fixed-style master view.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer at the [Apple Developers Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/941673#941673)

First make sure that the detail view controller has a reference to the popover view:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc {
    //Grab a reference to the popover
    self.popover = pc;
}
```

Then dismiss the popover when updating the detail view:

```
if (_popover != nil) {
    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sadly, `UIPopoverController` is deprecated in iOS 9, making this a dying solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UICollectionViewController` you can do

```
UISplitViewController *splitVC = (UISplitViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    splitVC.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
```